# Error 404 while accessing my app without / after context root

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a spring based web application. Below is web.xml

```
<display-name>testapp</display-name>    
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I have an index.jsp which contains below code.

```
<%response.sendRedirect("login");%>
```

Now if I am accessing my app with URL http://localhost:8080/myapp I am getting Error 404 but If I access my app with URL http://localhost:8080/myapp/ I am able to reach login page.

In my controller class I have below method to handle /login request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadLogin(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("loginForm", new LoginForm());
    return "login";
}
```

What is the difference here? How can I make http://localhost:8080/myapp (without /)  working? I am using Internet Explorer to access application.

Answer (score 0):

Here you problem is that the url `http://localhost:8080/myapp` doesn't exist because you have defined your  **DispatcherServlet** at /

i.e this is your code:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then when you try to access to `http://localhost:8080/myapp` your server is looking for any request like `/myapp` which doesn't exist.

Now if you want to access your application without a `/` at the end of your app
you need to change your defintion servlet like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myapp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but you would create a new controller that handle this /myapp looking for your view.

[EDIT]

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myapp/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadLogin(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("loginForm", new LoginForm());
    return "login";
}
```

Comment: I changed it then it redirected me correctly http://localhost:8080/myapp/login . But now I am getting 404. I n my controller class  I have defined a proper method. Controller method is added in question.

Comment: i have added a wild card in dispatcher context, then you can add your context in the controller to make it working, regards.